# Is there a reason it is -to omou instead of wo omou to say you think something?

Tags: grammar

I realize it is just something I got to remember, but is there any explenation to what is going on gramatically with to omou? Why to? Or is it just a thing that is?

Also, why to moushimasu/to iimasu, is the same thing happening there?

Comment: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/actionclause http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/define these should help too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because と and its colloquial version って are used to "quote" relative clauses.

They usually go with verbs like:

1. 言う 【い・う】 (u-verb) - to say
2. 聞く 【き・く】 (u-verb) - to ask; to listen
3. 叫ぶ 【さけ・ぶ】 (u-verb) - to scream
4. 呼ぶ 【よ・ぶ】 (u-verb) - to call
5. [思]{おも}う（u-verb) - to think

The same way you say:

> 今日、僕は大学に行かないと思う - I think I will not go to college today.

You also say:

> 彼はあなたに何と言った? - What did he say to you?

So with these verbs you will use と or って instead of を.

Comment: Are you sure "relative clause" is the right term here?

Comment: @Blavius From my studies that's the term "I think I will go to school", "I will go to school" is an complete sentence but in this context it's a relative clause to the full sentence. What do you think?

Comment: I think that it's wrong. This that is a conjunction so the right term seems to be 'noun clause' or 'object clause'.